# How to invert a domain using regex?

Tags: regex, sed, dns

I'm attempting to invert a domain for a few scripts I'm writing which use a unique name spacing.

So the input would look like example.com and output is com.example; while yes, I am aware of `s/\(\w\+\).*\(\w\+\)$/\2.\1/` method, the requirement is to be able to support multiple subdomains dynamically therefore the static `'\2.\1'` would not work. How would the BRE based POSIX REGEX look like?

Comment: I would also like to point out that tac(1) and perl(1) does not exist on all UNIX machines. Therefor unreliable on OSX, BSD, HP/UX, and Plan9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job. There are many ways you can do it, here is one:

```
address=www.example.com
dotted=$(echo $address. | tac -s.)
reversed=${dotted%?}
echo $reversed
# => com.example.www
```

**EDIT**: If you insist on sed and regular expressions:

```
echo 'www.example.com' | sed 's/\([^.]*\)\(\.\?\)\([^.]*\)\(\.\?\)\([^.]*\)\(\.\?\)\([^.]*\)\(\.\?\)\([^.]*\)/\9\8\7\6\5\4\3\2\1/g'
# => com.example.www
```

However, it will handle at maximum five components (`a.b.c.d.e`). If you want portability, jlhonora's answer is still the best.

Comment: +1 impressive use of an obscure option of a (relatively) obscure tool.

Comment: Nice of use of tac(1) albeit a little verbose on the script. How is the bash variable expansion (`${dotted%?}`) coming into play on your example?

Comment: @DwightSpencer: `tac` will carry the "line terminator" with the "line"; thus, `x.y.z.` can be turned into `z.y.x.`, but `x.y.z` is turned into `zy.x.` To avoid the problem, I add a dot before `tac`, and remove it after using `${...%?}`.

Comment: Ok you get a +1 for that, though this still does not answer the question; Sorry.

Comment: Cool edit, though I bet that could be condensed down using regex grouping?

Comment: @DwightSpencer: Nope. If you use repetition operators, you lose the ability to reverse the order.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`:

```
echo 'test.example.com' | awk -F '.' '{out=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ out=$i"."out}; print out}'
```

Comment: @jilhonora I just ran your example and it did not output the word reversing as I'm asking about. If I do `echo 'example.com' | ...` I get `example.com' this should be com.example, com.example.test, or com.example.www.app1 (given the input is app1.www.example.com)

Comment: `out"."$i` should be `$i"."out`; as it stands, it reconstructs the original line :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'G;:a;s/^\n//;s/^([^.\n]+)(\.*)(.*\n)/\3\2\1/;ta' file
```

This appends a newline and then appends each part of the domain after it.

When the last part has been appended the newline is removed.

Comment: @polong I love that you got that as a sed oneliner. Although, the newline is excessive. What is your thought of using the conditional '?' and grouping '{2,}'?

Comment: @DwightSpencer thanks. The newline is a unique marker to prevent the loop from never ending. It represents the base case. I don't understand the `conditional '?'` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant qualifier not conditional: http://regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html

Answer (score 0):

I would reach for a language that has arrays and a reverse function:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join ".", reverse split /\./' <<< "$domain"
```

Comment: Bash has arrays as of version 3.0 (circa 2008) while zsh has had them since circa 1999.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

Comment: As a followup so does rc: https://00080618404221498333.googlegroups.com/attach/183bd11de2c38b1f/array.rc?part=2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHqs7wE2fQnn5D1CBx_ouKOnThbvlleGV8K1RQsc9IAGOFZUn4ETjeTLSL63w-aiDySdJgRe2VfNba_ztfBPQv8jkzyXDj0rExxAU4Oxa7e_YlCRCM

Comment: I reached out for perl because bash doesn't have a nice `reverse` command. You'd have to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that should revert a dns name:

```
awk -F\. '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf "%s"(i==1?RS:FS),$i}'
```

Example:

```
echo 'test.example.com.br' | awk -F\. '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf "%s"(i==1?RS:FS),$i}'
br.com.example.test
```

---

This will work with any length DNS name:

```
this.is.my.dns.name.com.gov.us
```

gives

```
us.gov.com.name.dns.my.is.this
```

Comment: I hope I am understanding your awk script right. It looks like your using the . as the field seperator and then iterrating over the last field. From there its printing either results or field seperator. How is the `,$i` comming into play?

Comment: The `for` loop counts every field from last field to first using the variable `i`, so for `www.google.com` the `i` would become `3 2 1`. Using the `$` in front of an variable, give the corresponding field. So here: `i=2` then `$i` gives `$2`, and it gives second field `google`